# Transform array of objects using lodash or ramda

Tags: javascript, lodash, ramda.js

This is the data structure that I got after doing query database.

```
[
    { name: 'xx1', date: '2017-09-03', value: 49 },
    { name: 'xx2', date: '2017-10-23', value: 67 },
    { name: 'xx2', date: '2017-12-01', value: 70 },
    ...
]
```

I want to transform it into:

```
[
    { name: 'xx1', data: { '2017-09-03': 49 } },
    { name: 'xx2', data: { '2017-10-23': 67, '2017-12-01': 70 } },
    ...
]
```

That data structure is needed in order to build chart using [react-chartkick](https://github.com/ankane/react-chartkick).

Can anyone give me suggestion to solve this? (Especially with lodash or ramda)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use following approach based on `reduce` and `find` (ES6) methods:

```
const data = [
  { name: 'xx1', date: '2017-09-03', value: 49 },
  { name: 'xx2', date: '2017-10-23', value: 67 },
  { name: 'xx2', date: '2017-12-01', value: 70 }
];

const result = data.reduce((acc, item) => {
  const found = acc.find(a => a.name === item.name);
  if (found) {
     found.data[item.date] = item.value;
  } else {
    acc.push({
      name: item.name,
      data: {
        [item.date]: item.value
      }
    });
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
```

If you don't want ES6, both methods have `lodash` versions: [reduce](https://lodash.com/docs/#reduce), [find](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#find).

Comment: Fantastic! Many thanks, shishou! I never know about `reduce` before. Thanks for sharing :)

Answer (score 2):

You can accumulate an object with [`Array#reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and return its [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/Values):

```js
const data = [
  { name: 'xx1', date: '2017-09-03', value: 49 },
  { name: 'xx2', date: '2017-10-23', value: 67 },
  { name: 'xx2', date: '2017-12-01', value: 70 }
]
const map = data.reduce((acc, { name, date, value }) => {
  if (!(name in acc)) {
    acc[name] = { name, data: {} }
  }

  acc[name].data[date] = value

  return acc
}, {})
const result = Object.values(map)

console.log(result)
```

This approach avoids using `Array#find()` which is O(n) time complexity and uses `name in acc` to check for existence and `acc[name]` for access, which are both O(1) time complexity, making this approach O(n) overall.

In contrast, [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51334567/1541563) is O(n<sup>2</sup>) time complexity overall.

Answer (score 1):

For a solution using lodash, you can use its `_.map`, `_.groupBy`, and `_.merge` methods to accomplish this.

I find it's easier to follow using the `_.chain` style, but you can easily convert it to a normal set of nested calls if you like.

```js
const data = [
    { name: 'xx1', date: '2017-09-03', value: 49 },
    { name: 'xx2', date: '2017-10-23', value: 67 },
    { name: 'xx2', date: '2017-12-01', value: 70 },
]

const result = _.chain(data)
  .map(val => ({name: val.name, data: {[val.date]: val.value}})) // convert objects to desired format
  .groupBy("name")                                               // group objects by name
  .map(v => _.merge(...v))                                       // merge objects in each group
  .value();                                                      // done!
  
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: With the [pipeline operator proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-pipeline-operator) and the [partial application proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-partial-application) you'd be able to do `data |> _.map(?, val => ({name: val.name, data: {[val.date]: val.value}})) |> _.groupBy(?, 'name') |> _.map(?, v => _.merge(...v))` which I quite like the style of as well.

Comment: Also you can simplify your `map` function to `.map(({ name, date, value }) => ({ name, data: { [date]: value } }))`

Answer (score 1):

Ramda's [`R.reduceBy`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#reduceBy) or [`R.groupBy`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#groupBy) can help you here. In the example below `R.reduceBy` groups the objects in the array by their `name` property and then combines the grouped elements by building up the new object with [`R.assoc`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#assoc). The remaining combination of [`R.toPairs`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#toPairs), [`R.map`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#map) and [`R.zipObj`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#zipObj) will get the result into the shape you want.

```js
const fn = R.pipe(
  R.reduceBy((res, {date, value}) => R.assoc(date, value, res), {}, R.prop('name')),
  R.toPairs,
  R.map(R.zipObj(['name', 'data']))
)

const data = [
    { name: 'xx1', date: '2017-09-03', value: 49 },
    { name: 'xx2', date: '2017-10-23', value: 67 },
    { name: 'xx2', date: '2017-12-01', value: 70 }
]

console.log(fn(data))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```